# NSNotificationCenter , prints memory address

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nslog

I have in my app a UITableview Controller, a View Controller and I'm trying to pass NSDictionary from UITableview Controller to my ViewController, using NSNotificationCenter. So, I  push a notification at my UITableview Controller and then I add an observer ,using a selector at my ViewController.The selector is called,but I have an NSLog and get memory results ,like :

> ViewController: 0x8a0bcc0

I have tried to pass NSString instead of NSDictionary , but I get again memory results , and not the value of the string.

My code :

**UITableView Controller**

```
    NSString *string=@"This is a test string";
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"Update" object: string];
```

**ViewController**

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"Update" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Update" object:self];
```

And here is the incomingNotification selector method:

```
-(void) incomingNotification : (NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"Trying to print : %@",[notification object]);
}
```

All Notifications take place at ViewDidLoad method.Thank you!

***UPDATE***

Finally , I quit using NSNotificationCenter and used properties to pass data ,changing a bit the inheretence from my TableViewController. No idea why Notifications did not work ,as they were supposed to. Thank you all ,very much for your suggestions and ideas :)

Comment: why do you post a second notification in `ViewController` right after adding an observer? Thats why you got this string in console. What about why there is no test string - make sure that you adding an observer BEFORE posting a notification in table controller (set a breakpoints to watch the order of them)

Comment: You call postNotification with object self in ViewController so the print out is your own object.

Comment: If i delete the second notification in ViewController ,then the selector method is not called!I'll  try to set breakpoints now!

Comment: UPDATE: I'm pretty sure that this issue happens,because firstly i post the notification and then i add the observer(order of execution issue).Is there a way to solve it?I should firstly post  the notification and then parse it.Can i add an observer ,post the notification(at my TableViewController) and then parse it from my ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Update" object:self]
```

Object means the object that generates a notification. To post parameters use another method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Update" object:self userInfo:string]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ,but again selector method is not called ,when i delete the extraneous ViewController observer.When i have it -using now your suggestion- , i get again memory address results.

Comment: The `userInfo` has to be a dictionary, but that's a minor change.

Comment: Yes!I don't think that's the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `UIViewController` is shown after you tap a button on `UITableViewController`. And you if you are adding a `ViewController` as observer in its `-viewDidLoad:`, then it will be able to receive notifications only when it is loaded.

What do you need:

1) override `-init` or `-initWithNibName:` method of `ViewController` like this:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"Update" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

so you can be sure `ViewController` is observing for notifications from the beginning (well, this might be unnecessary step for your case)

2) when you push `ViewController` you need to send a notification after it was created, like this:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *nextController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

    NSString *string=@"This is a test string";
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"Update" object: string];
}
```

However, if you're trying just to send some parameters from one view controller to another, this is the wrong way. Just create a property in `ViewController` and in method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:` of `UITableViewController` set this property

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions!You have exactly understood the case.I tried what you said,but nothing happened.My ViewController is created from storyboard,and the i use performSegueWithIdentifier to perform the segue from my -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath delegate method. So,i shouldn't alloc the ViewController.Moreover,the reason why i use NSNotificationCenter, is the fact that i can't subclass ViewController to UITableviewController and get info from it!

Comment: Nick,i have also tried initwithCoder method.This is also not working.

Comment: try to subscribe to notification in `ViewController`'s `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method, and post a notification right after `-performSegueWithIdentifier`. Also you can get `ViewController` from the segue: `[segue destinationViewController];` so you can set properties instead of using notifications

Comment: Thank you Nick.I have tried everything,and still have the same issue.I quit notifications , and start setting properties . No idea why notification center is not working as expected.